# Is casting a pointer to a pointer to an array considered UB?

Tags: c++

Recently I wondered if I could explicitly define what a pointer is and explicitly determine its type. Let's say we use the `new operator` in the expression `auto* x = new int[4];` which returns us `int*`. But I want to protect myself from possible errors and want to explicitly indicate the size of the elements in the pointer.

I found that you can define a pointer to an array of the form `T(*name)[size]`. Is this kind of pointer casting considered UB? We seem to be preserving the basic pointer type by adding information, does this violate the rules of type aliases?

```
int main()
{
     auto* p = new int[10];
     decltype(auto) n = (int(*)[10])(p);
     *n[1]=1;
}
```

Comment: It's preferable in C++ to use `static_cast<...>(p)` rather than C-style casts.

Comment: Please only ask one question per post. Now the answer to your UB question will be different from the one about how to use `n`. You can only accept one of them.

Comment: But I don't see any reason why this would be UB. `new` returns a pointer to an array, and you're casting to that type.

Comment: You can only do this if your array bound is a compile-time constant, but if it is then why are you using `new` at all?

Comment: @MilesBudnek I'm writing template libraries, and recently I've been getting memory errors because user code doesn't determine the size of arrays when allocating. I'd be interested in trying to put this back into a function call like `make_new<int[8]>()` that would return an array pointer.

Comment: BTW, You probably want `(*n)[1]` to avoid out of bound access.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That C-style cast `(int(*)[10]) p` is equivalent to a `reinterpret_cast`.

`reinterpret_cast` is very difficult to work with. You formally have UB, where `n` is a pointer of type "pointer to `int[10]`", but it is a pointer to the first element of the array (the same as `p`), not the array itself. These are defined to have the same address, but that does not matter, `n` is not usable to access the array.

This is where the function [`std::launder`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/launder) comes in: You can launder that pointer to get a pointer to the actual array object instead of its first element.

```cpp
int main()
{
     using ten_ints = int[10];
     int* p = new ten_ints;
     ten_ints* n = std::launder(reinterpret_cast<ten_ints*>(p));
     (*n)[1]=1;
     assert(p[1] == 1);
}
```

But this is difficult to work with and you should come up with alternate solutions, like:

```cpp
int main() {
    {
        using ten_ints = std::array<int, 10>;
        ten_ints* p = new ten_ints;  // Pointer to std::array, doesn't "decay"
    }
    {
        using ten_ints = std::span<int, 10>;
        int* p = new int[10];
        ten_ints s(p, 10);  // Use a span of size 10
    }
}
```

... And of course not using `new` entirely, but using another container like `std::vector` which can hold the size.

Comment: I expected to use a launder, but I was not sure that I understood what I was doing correctly. What can you say about casting a pointer to a reference? For example `(int(&)[10])*reinterpret_cast<int(*)[10]>(p)`

Comment: @yatanai The reference case works almost entirely the same as a pointer. You can do `int(&arr)[10] = *std::launder(reinterpret_cast<int(*)[10]>(p))` or `int(&arr)[10] = *std::launder(&reinterpret_cast<int(&)[10]>(*p))`. (You can only use `std::launder` with pointers, but you can indirect through it immediately afterward). In `(int(&)[10])*reinterpret_cast<int(*)[10]>(p)`, the `(int(&)[10])` is a static_cast because `*reinterpret_cast<int(*)[10]>(p)` is already an lvalue `int[10]`

Comment: For clarity, remember that it's not the `reinterpret_cast` that's UB ("not the fall that kills you") but the access using the wrong-type result.